# SharePoint 2007 documents Connection to server was reset

Tags: error, sharepoint-server

Recently our SharePoint 2007 system started giving the error "the Connection was reset by the server" when loading some pages. At first we thought it was just html documents uploaded by users, however I found a few of the .aspx pages that are doing the same thing. I checked the SharePoint and windows logs and have found nothing that points to the issue. After a great deal of troubleshooting I did find that all the documents that are having troubles being displayed have a VML namespace declared in the document. Generally it looks like this:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

I did some packet sniffing and as far as I can tell when the request fails the server starts to send the data then sends a TCP packet with the reset flag set to true.

Do any of you have an idea of where to look to find why the server is resetting the connections on these documents?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here.........any anti-virus or firewall running on the servers?  What about some sort of intrusion detection system on your network that might be shooting down the connections based on content?

Comment: If you can, you might want to run wireshark (or your choice of tool) on the WFE of your SharePoint farm.  That way you could be sure that the WFE is or is not sending the TCP Reset packet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found that the server gets a TCP reset packet that claims it’s from the requesting machine, but as I mentioned in the post, the requesting machine gets a TCP reset packet claiming it’s from the Server. There is no anti-virus or firewall on the machine it’s all done in the network. I'm assuming you are right about something else in the network shooting down the connection. Thanks for that extra advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with the network admin, found out our IPS was recently updated and it had a new rule that was blocking some of the VML documents. Thanks for the help!